# Can Apps Made in Applescript Editor Be Submitted to the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, applescript

Can you submit apps made in AppleScript editor to the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they're made with AppleScript Studio (-> with Xcode), there is no reason to get rejected, I'd think...

Take a look at [this](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/10/20/apple_issues_review_guidelines_for_mac_app_store.html). It doesn't look like they're disallowing apps like that...